# Low resolution on second monitor, xrandr throws error

Tags: xrandr

When I connect an external monitor to my laptop through VGA cable, it has extremely low resolutions and no higher options to choose from.

I tried the following (based on [this](http://unliterate.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/fixing-external-monitor-resolutionmode-in-ubuntu/); other sites just suggest the same approach) (restarting doesn't help)

```
$ gtf 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
$ xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

The monitor is a Philips Brilliance 231B. When turned on, it shows 'Use 1920x1080@60Hz for best results'.

I don't know much about this so it could well be something trivial. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

---

Don' know if it's relevant but `xrandr` shows (after the above steps):

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2320 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        59.9*+
   320x240       120.1  
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected 1680x1050+640+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x270)  172.8MHz
    h: width  1920 start 2040 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.1KHz
    v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock   60.0Hz
```

Comment: The solution you describe worked for me. Are you still having trouble with it?